# To connect to live Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

when i run this command:>npm run dev

> restapi@1.0.0 dev
> nodemon index.js

[nodemon] 2.0.20
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Error while connecting

```
 db = client.db('Aug_22');
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'db')
```

trying to connect to live mongodb

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not nodemon that makes problem, it is database connection probably.
Check the way you defined your client. Suppose there is some mistake, as error refers...